# How can I pass this jQuery counter plugin a variable integer and have it update properly with animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, counter, updates

i am trying to find a reliable way to pass this jQuery counter plugin a new value (integer) and have it update:

http://jsfiddle.net/ucxpr/4/

Counter Code From Here:
https://github.com/sophilabs/jquery-counter

I have my code setup using the plugins built-in "data-stop" attribute which is currently set at 10... So the counter starts... and counts up to 10 and then stops... I am hoping to trigger the update when the user clicks the #incrementCounter button in my code:

```
<button id="incrementCounter">Click here</button>

$('#incrementCounter').click(function($) {

        $('.counter-analog').attr('data-stop', '25');

});
```

I figured the best way to increment the counter would just be to modify the data-stop attribute on my span and re-initialize the counter but it doesn't seem to work :-/ ?

Help is greatly appreciated!... Again... I am just trying to figure out a way to make this counter reliably count up to a number that I give it and then stop! :)

I also have tried this with no success:

```
$('.main_counter .counter-analog').counter({startTime: "25"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rerun the counter, but pass the new stop-variable

http://jsfiddle.net/Hed9F/1/

```
$('#incrementCounter').click(function() {
    $('.main_counter .counter-analog').counter({'stop': 25});       
});
```

Comment: Thank you!... I was trying inital: & starttime: dunno why it didn't occur to me to try stop!... Duh ;P